# Passing arguments to function along with positional arguments

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I wanted to validate the arguments(-date  -dir  ...) passed while invoking the script. How to make the position parameters($#) and parameters($@) visible inside a function validate_args:

```
validate_args "$@"

validate_args(){
   while [[ $# -ne 0 ]]
    do
      case $1 in
              -date date="$2"
                    shift 2
                    ;;
              -dir  dir="$2"
                    shift 2
                    ;;
              *)    echo "Invalid arguments"
                    exit 1
                    ;; 
       esac
    done
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, since the code sample you've given seems to answer the question as I would have interpreted it.  Do you perhaps mean that you want the function to modify the positional parameters in the calling scope?

Comment: Or is your question about the syntax of the `case` statement?

Comment: The arguments are not visible inside validate_args

Comment: Yes, the arguments are visible, because you've explicitly passed them.  `ksh -c 'foo() { echo $#; }; foo "$@"' _ arg1 arg2` will print `2`, because `$#` is visible in the function.  You'll need to clarify the question.

Comment: Although perhaps the problem is merely that you are calling the function before you define it.  The syntax errors indicate that the code you've posted is not the code you're using.

Comment: yes, this seems to work. I was assuming I have to get the value passed to function as $1 as we usually do. Thanks